# MonoDevelop: same project for MonoMac and GTK# possible?

Tags: mono, monodevelop, gtk#

Perhaps my question is totally naiive and this is the reason why I couldn't find any information with Google or something else - but nonetheless, I think it is worth asking here.

I want to develop a C# application which behaves naturally in Mac and Windows (Linux would also be nice, but is not directly needed). My main operating system for development should be Mac OS X and therefore I want to go with MonoDevelop.

I can setup a project for MonoMac - works fine.
I can setup a different project for GTK# - works fine.

My question is now, what I have to do to get a project with a possibility for a MonoMac and a GTK#-frontend. So I will go with the MVC pattern and want to work in one project. As a result, building my project would result in a Mac executable (based on the MonoMac stuff) and one windows executable (based on GTK#).

Am I completely wrong with my approach?
What do I have to do to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, for a multi-platform app with the best possible look-n-feel on each platform, you would need one executable per platform. Using an MVC approach is the best way to do this - you can have a solution containing a library project with all the shared code - models, processing code, business logic, etc - and a project for each "frontend" executable containing the platform-specific views and shell.

If a really good native experience on Windows is higher priority than Linux support, I'd recommend using WPF or Windows Forms instead of GTK#. This would mean you'd have to split development between Windows and MacOS - you would need to open the same project in Visual Studio, SharpDevelop or MonoDevelop on Windows, and edit the WPF/WinForms project and the shared library there.

OTOH, GTK# has the advantage you could start off writing a single frontend that would work on all three platforms, and then write the platform-specific ones afterwards.

Comment: I think it is not possible (at the moment) to directly/automatically create an app bundle for a Gtk# app from MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio. That nice feature seems to be (unfortunately) only available for Xamarin.Mac and MonoMac projects (but not for Gtk#).